# C: Nested do while loop not looping correctly

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops, do-while

This code is supposed to -

- Count the number of characters from input sequence.
- Repeat the action until user exits the program.
- Use nested do-while loop to achieve this purpose.

But the inner loop is executed only once.

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int x;
    char i, ans;
    i = '\0';
    do
    {
        i = '\0';
        x=0;
        printf("\nEnter sequence of character:");
        do
        {
            i = getchar();
            x++;
        }
        while(i!='\n');
        printf("\nNumber of characters entered is: %d", --x);
        printf("\nMore sequences (Y/N) ?");
        ans = getchar();
    }
    while(ans =='Y' || ans == 'y');
```

Answer (score 2):

After you read the answer yes/no (the line with `ans = getchar();`), you'll read an `"y"` and a `"\n"`. You'll consume the `"y"` and process it, but the next iteration when you read `i = getchar();`, `i` will consume the remaining `"\n"`, so will break that do-while loop.

Although it's not my favourite solution, a simple workaround is this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int x;
    char i, ans;
    i = '\0';
    do
    {
        i = '\0';
        x=0;
        printf("\nEnter sequence of character:");
        do
        {
            i = getchar();
            x++;
        }
        while(i!='\n');
        printf("\nNumber of characters entered is: %d", --x);
        printf("\nMore sequences (Y/N) ?");
        ans = getchar();

        getchar();
    }
    while(ans =='Y' || ans == 'y');
}
```

So just consume that extra `"\n"`. This will work only if you type `"y"` followed by `"\n"` in terminal. If you type any extra characters, you'll have undefined behaviour.

Note: In your version, try to type: `"y1234"` then enter when prompted if you want to input again. You'll see that in fact the nested do-while loop works and will count the 4 characters after `"y"`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure, but I think that when the user presses enter to finish the 1st input character the input buffer keeps then enter button as the `\n` character. Try adding `if(i == '\n') getChar();` after the `x++;`.

Comment: It would need to be `if (I == ’\n’)`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

**What happened:**

- `getchar` is a macro that gets a character from `stdin`.
- The delimiter (`'\n'` in this case) is counted as a separate
  character that remains in the buffer and is retrieved the next time
  `getchar()` is called.
- This causes inner loop to exit.

**What could be done:**

- Insert the following after `ans = getchar();`

```
    i = getchar();
    if(i != '\n')
        ungetc(i,stdin);
```

**New code explained:**

- `ungetc(int x,FILE *stream)` pushes a character back into input stream.
- `stdin` is the standard input stream defined in `<stdio.h>`.
- We are reading a character and putting it back if it is not `'\n'`.